# SQLite TOTAL query increases when join condition added

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to get the sum of payments from a SQLite database using this (simplified) schema

```
CREATE TABLE [Orders] (
    [OrderId] text   NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE
    ,PRIMARY KEY ([OrderId])
);
CREATE TABLE [OrderDetails] (
    [OrderDetailId] text   NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE
    ,[OrderId] text   NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE
    ,PRIMARY KEY ([OrderDetailId])
    FOREIGN KEY ( [OrderId]) REFERENCES [Orders]( [OrderId] )
);
CREATE TABLE [Payments] (
    [OrderId] text   NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE
    ,[PaymentAmount] numeric   NOT NULL 
    ,[PaymentDate] datetime   NOT NULL 
    ,[PaymentId] text   NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE
    ,PRIMARY KEY ([PaymentId])
    FOREIGN KEY ( [OrderId]) REFERENCES [Orders]( [OrderId] )
```

This query returns the correct result

```
SELECT  
TOTAL(PaymentAmount) AS Paid 
FROM Orders LEFT JOIN Payments ON Orders.OrderId=Payments.OrderId
```

However if I also JOIN on OrderDetails like this

```
SELECT  
TOTAL(PaymentAmount) AS Paid 
FROM Orders LEFT JOIN Payments ON Orders.OrderId=Payments.OrderId
INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderId=OrderDetails.OrderId
```

the amount paid increases. Why are the results different?

**EDIT** If there is a single PaymentAmount of $50 the query without a join returns Paid=50. The query with a join returns Paid=100.

Comment: You probably have multiple orderdetails for one order, so the order row (and therefore also the payment) appears multiple times in the result

Comment: @derpirscher you are correct. There are typically multiple details for each order. However I do need to also retrieve information from order details so I do need the join. How do I get the correct total of payments when I include the order details join?

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: Your 1st query, which you say returns the correct result, returns only 1 row with 1 column: the total of `PaymentAmount`. Why do you want to join `OrderDetails`? If you want to get more info from the new query you must post your expected results.

Comment: I'm trying to keep a complex query simple to focus on the issue. I don't think the reason for joining on order details is relevant, but say for example I also wanted a count of the order details. In that case I would want to return both the payments total and the order detail count.

Comment: Your query only returns the total payment. So why do you need to join order details? They are not returned in the result. Please post your some example data and the REAL expected result from that data ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the amount paid increases. Why are the results different?

Because you are joining a row for each combination of Order Payment and OrderDetails. Thus for an Order with 5 payments and 3 Order Details then there will be 15 rows and thus 3 times the payments (as there 3 Order Details).

Consider the following example of utilising your SQL (but with the Total Aggregate function removed, so the rows can be seen):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Payments;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS OrderDetails;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Orders;
CREATE TABLE [Orders] (
    [OrderId] text   NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE
    ,PRIMARY KEY ([OrderId])
);
CREATE TABLE [OrderDetails] (
    [OrderDetailId] text   NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE
    ,[OrderId] text   NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE
    ,PRIMARY KEY ([OrderDetailId])
    FOREIGN KEY ( [OrderId]) REFERENCES [Orders]( [OrderId] )
);
CREATE TABLE [Payments] (
    [OrderId] text   NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE
    ,[PaymentAmount] numeric   NOT NULL 
    ,[PaymentDate] datetime   NOT NULL 
    ,[PaymentId] text   NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE
    ,PRIMARY KEY ([PaymentId])
    FOREIGN KEY ( [OrderId]) REFERENCES [Orders]( [OrderId] )
);
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES ('Order1'),('Order2'),('Order3');
INSERT INTO OrderDetails VALUES
    ('OrderDetail001','Order1'),('OrderDetail002','Order1'),('OrderDetail003','Order1'),
    ('OrderDetail010','Order2'),
    ('OrderDetail020','Order3')
;
INSERT INTO Payments VALUES
    ('Order1',10,datetime('now'),'PayOrder1001'),
    ('Order1',15,datetime('now'),'PayOrder1002'),
    ('Order1',5,datetime('now'),'PayOrder1003'),
    ('Order1',12,datetime('now'),'PayOrder1004'),
    ('Order1',8,datetime('now'),'PayOrder1005'),
    
    ('Order2',10,datetime('now'),'PayOrder2001'),
    ('Order2',7,datetime('now'),'PayOrder2002'),
    ('Order2',5,datetime('now'),'PayOrder2003')
    
;

SELECT  
TOTAL(PaymentAmount) AS Paid 
FROM Orders LEFT JOIN Payments ON Orders.OrderId=Payments.OrderId
;

SELECT  
/* TOTAL(PaymentAmount) AS Paid */ * 
FROM Orders LEFT JOIN Payments ON Orders.OrderId=Payments.OrderId
LEFT JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderId=OrderDetails.OrderId 
;

SELECT  
TOTAL(PaymentAmount) AS Paid 
FROM Orders LEFT JOIN Payments ON Orders.OrderId=Payments.OrderId
LEFT JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderId=OrderDetails.OrderId 
;
```

In this case the total payments made are 72 (50 for Order1 and 22 for Order2) and this is reflected by your first Query as per :-

[image]

The 2nd Query (your's less the Total Aggregate function and thus showing the rows extracted) :-

[image]

- As you can see there are as many order payments for the same payment as there OrderDetails (and hence WHY)

and if you add all the payments up it's 3 * 50 + 22 = 172

as per the third query (yours) :-

[image]

Comment: how then, would you construct a query that did require a join on order details. Say for example I had to return both the total payments and the count of order details?

Comment: To simply return the count of order details you could do this without a join using `SELECT  
TOTAL(PaymentAmount) AS Paid, (SELECT count(*) FROM OrderDetails) AS OrderDetailCount
FROM Orders LEFT JOIN Payments ON Orders.OrderId=Payments.OrderId
;` Result = 172 and 5. You may wish to have a read of https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html. You could do more complex and perhaps useful queries using CTE's and or Windows functions.